# how to get data-id using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I want to get data-id from html but when i click on the link i got this error..!
Comment_id is not defined
here is my html code

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="<?php echo $row->video_comment_id ?>" data-action="<?php echo site_url('videosd/commentslike');?>" class="video_comment_like">
like
</a>
```

I am fetching `$row->video_Comment_id` from data base.
Here is my jQuery code

```
$('.video_comment_like').click(function(){
    var coment_id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(comment_id)
});
```

and i also tried `$(this).attr('data-action');` but its not working.

Comment: using firebug have you checked whether the data-id="<?php echo $row->video_comment_id ?>"  showing valid id? Does a tag loaded dynamically?

Comment: yup i checked using firebug its showing..

Comment: console.log(coment_id) try this

Comment: You had spelling mistake `coment_id` &  calling `comment_id`

Answer (score 2):

Its a typo `coment_id` & `comment_id` -

```
var comment_id = $(this).data("id");
console.log(comment_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the attr() function

```
$('.video_comment_like').click(function(){
    var comment_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(comment_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

var coment_id = $(this).attr('data-id');